# DNS issues on a single Wifi - Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dns, resolv.conf, nslookup

I'm having DNS problems with one WiFi network which I've been using for a long time. I tried to do an hotspot with my phone and everything worked as normal, so the issue is only on that network.
`ping 8.8.8.8` works, but

```
nslookup google.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.53, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I've tried to install `resolvconf` and other solutions found online but none of them worked.

This is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` (after adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`):

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search station
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager to configure the network on your system? It could be an issue with the DHCP service not providing correct DNS information.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq` solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks! Your comment helped me to find a solution. I added `dns=dnsmasq` to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and now it works. But, just out of curiosity, do you know what could have caused this issue? I'm wondering because I've been using this network for quite a while

Comment: 127.0.0.53 is an address of your machine and not of the network, maybe a security update or package installation put it out of work. I would advise writing your own answer in the answer field and accepting it in two days. I usually prefer to unistall resolvconf in my machines.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to

1. Make sure [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is installed (`sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`)
2. add `dns=dnsmasq` in the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`